# Python: how to add '-help' to argparse help command list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Is there a way to include '-help' command to argparse help list?

I wish to have something like this on output, if i am typing '-help'.

```
optional arguments:
-h, -help, --help            show this help message and exit
```

Thanks

Comment: `-help` isn't a valid argument form for `argparse`. It should be one dash for a letter, double dash for a word. `-help` would be four arguments, `h`, `e`, `l` and `p`.

Comment: and for a good reason: they would violate [POSIX conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)

Comment: if your users can't work out how to specify `-h` or `--help`, then i think there is little hope that they can use the tool correctly ;)

Comment: Mind that if you want to have a workaround for that, just create dummy `-e`, `-l` and `-p` arguments and `-help` will actually print the help message. However, this is NOT recommended.

Comment: @khelwood Have you tried it?  I did a quick test, defining a multi-letter option with a single dash, and it seems to work.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes you're right, it does seem to work. `argparse` will do its best to parse those arguments, though it can cause errors because the parsing is ambiguous.

Comment: I realize that some of the above comments insist that this doesn't work, but they are incorrect.  This works:  `parser.add_argument("-help", action="help")`  It may not be posix-compliant, but I tried it and it does work.  `argparse` does allow multi-letter options with a single hyphen.

Comment: What about getting the argument using sys and then calling argparse directly? This is fun.

Comment: In my workplace is '-help' standard.

Comment: With a bit of under-the-covers work I think I could add '-help' to the list of option-strings that the default help argument accepts.  Another option is to initialize the parser with `add_help=False`, and define your own help argument (with `action='help').  I could demonstrate that later.

Comment: @norok2 Argparse makes **no mention of POSIX** and a lot of these comments are **personal preference**. `argparse` can work with any delimiter, including `/`, `+`, `-` or `--`, the default help option just happens to be POSIX, but this is useless if your **target audience** is e.g. Powershell.

Comment: @cz Not sure what is your point. If you mix single and double delimiter options, this may lead to unexpected behaviors. `help` is a bit of its own kind, because no matter what the other options are, the `help` action just prints the help and quit, but if you have regular options, and one option is (`-abc`, `-a`), this shadows `-b` and `-c`, so that `-abc` actually only triggers `-a` while `-acb` (and all other permutations) also trigger `-b` and `-c`. Following POSIX recommendations (which are personal preferences) would allow you to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Akaisteph7 suggested:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-help', action="help", help="second help :)")
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')

parser.print_help()

0945:~/mypy$ python3 stack57058526.py 
usage: stack57058526.py [-h] [-help] [-f FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -help              second help :)
  -f FOO, --foo FOO
```

Changing to:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-h','--help','-help', action="help", help="replacement help")

0946:~/mypy$ python3 stack57058526.py 
usage: stack57058526.py [-h] [-f FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help, -help  replacement help
  -f FOO, --foo FOO
```

Adding the '-help' flag to the default help requires modifying a couple of 'private' attributes:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser._actions[0].option_strings += ['-help']                                                          
parser._option_string_actions['-help'] = parser._option_string_actions['-h']  

0947:~/mypy$ python3 stack57058526.py 
usage: stack57058526.py [-h] [-f FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help, -help  show this help message and exit
  -f FOO, --foo FOO
```

If you want to build this change into your local version of `argparse`, you could modify this block of code in the `ArgumentParser.__init__` method:

```
    if self.add_help:
        self.add_argument(
            default_prefix+'h', default_prefix*2+'help',
            action='help', default=SUPPRESS,
            help=_('show this help message and exit'))
```

Whether you change a local copy of `argparse.py`, or subclass `ArgumentParser` is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

While this is possible to do, it is not recommended. Single dashes are only meant to be used with single letters. In general, you should follow recommendations as they are there for a reason.

If you really want to add it however, you can do it with:

```
parser.add_argument("-help", action="help")
```

Comment: This is the simplest.  The downside is that a help argument appears twice in the help and usage.

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` can work with any prefix characters.
For instance to support POSIX, Cmd.exe and PowerShell-type queries you could use:

```
p = ArgumentParser(prefix_chars="-/", add_help=False)
p.add_argument("-help", "--help", "-h", "/?", action="help")
```

Remember to use `add_help=False` or you'll have two help commands!